# Why is PyTorch handling similar weight update assignments differently?

Tags: python, pytorch

The below code does work updating the weights using:

```
w -= lr * w.grad
```

But when updating the weights using

```
w = w - lr * w.grad
```

it throws me:

> element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Why is that and shouldn't both assignments be equal?

```
import torch

X = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=torch.float32)
y = torch.tensor([2, 4, 6, 8], dtype=torch.float32)
w = torch.tensor(0.0, dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True)
epochs = 10
lr = 0.002

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    y_pred = w * X
    loss = ((y_pred - y)**2).mean()
    loss.backward()
    
    print(w.grad)
    with torch.no_grad():
        ### Option 1 - doesn't work
        w = w - lr * w.grad

        ### Option 2 - does work
        w -= lr * w.grad
        
    w.grad.zero_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `-=` is an in-place op and the alternative is not. Therefore, when using `-=` inside the `.no_grad()` context, the variable will compute the operation, but the gradient won't take that op into account.

When you perform a normal subtraction, you'd expect a `SubBackward` as `grad_fn`:

```py
import torch
x = torch.tensor([3.], requires_grad=True)
print(x)
# >>> tensor([3.], requires_grad=True)

x = x - 2
print(x)
# >>> tensor([1.], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
```

and indeed, this is what we get. But, if we try `-=` inside the `.no_grad()` context:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    x -= 2

print(x)
# >>> tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
```

we get the expected result (i.e., 2), but no backward function (ofc, we specified that with `.no_grad()`). **Note that it still `requires_grad=True`**. However, if we try to run this in-place op out of the `.no_grad()` context, this is what happens:

```py
x -= 2
# >>> Traceback (most recent call last):
# >>>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# >>> RuntimeError: a leaf Variable that requires grad has been used in an in-place operation.
```

and if we try to run the normal subtraction inside the `.no_grad()` context, we will get:

```py
x = x - 2
print(x)
# >>> tensor([-1.])
```

a **tensor without `requires_grad`**; and that is the reason you get the error when using this option.